# Compare two String by length only in a special class using __eq__?

Tags: python, class, compare, magic-methods

I'm trying to create a Class to compare two String only by length (using the Magic method). Here is my code:

```
class CustomString:
    def __init__(self,string):
        self.string=string
        
    def __eq__(self,other):
        if len(self.string) == len(other.string):
            return True
        else:
            return False
spam = CustomString('spam')
eggs = CustomString('eggs')

spam==eggs
```

I don't know where is wrong but in the end, it returned nothing at all. My IDE also said that "Statement appears to have no effect" at the `spam=eggs` line. I also need to write `__gt__` and `__lt__`, but I think I need to understand how `__eq__` work first.

I really appreciate it if someone could show me what is wrong. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Using the operator alone will not do anything with the result. The operation will still happen, but you won't see a difference. You could e.g. `print(spam==eggs)` to see the result, or save it to a variable, e.g. `result = spam==eggs`

Comment: I've run your code, and it returns True as expected. If you are working in a script (and not a shell/interpreter), you should place `print(spam==eggs)` if you want the output to be shown

Comment: An expression statement (like `spam == eggs`) evaluates the expression, but does *nothing* with the result. Expression statements are used for the *side effects* of the expression. For example, if you had used `print` statements inside `CustomString.__eq__`, you would see the output, even if you ignore the `bool` value produced as the result.

Comment: Oh my god, how can I forget this? I forgot to add the print function, what a stupid mistake and it took me 30 minutes. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, everyone! I just forgot to add a print function. Just add print(spam==eggs) work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but you forget to add a print function. It should be `print(spam==eggs)` just like `print(1==1)`